# Queries in a Jquery Webchat

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm thinking about a webchat working with PHP, JQuery and MySQL but I'm in some trouble about how the queries should be send to the db.

- Structure:

MySQL receives all data from chat and saves it like in a table "conversation" with columns from/to.

Jquery do the queries and verifies if there is any new message for the current user.

- Problem:

How to do the queries with Jquery in a way to not overload the db server (in consideration to have a lot of users)? I think to query the db with a timer in Jquery, so within some secs. a new query will be done and it will be repeated for all users at same time.

Comment: PHP is not the best choice for a chat application. You might need to take some research with `nodejs` chat App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it (according to me) is to have a 1 second interval in jquery. Once a second you call a php file (fetch_new.php for example).

In your database, you have two tables:

1. users
2. messages

When a user client makes a call to **fetch_new.php** (through JavaScript), you update the *users* table and set a column (last_sync) to the current time (preferably in microtime, that way the user will never get two of the same messages sent to them). The new message(s) get appended to the conversation.

When you execute your query, it should look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `to` = $user_id AND `timestamp` > $last_sync
```

It is perfectly fine to send many questions per second to MySQL as long as it can handle many connections (enough RAM and CPU). Keep an eye on the "Status" tab in PHPMyAdmin to see how much CPU and RAM is being used.

In the chat applications I've built I've added some "intelligence" features. If a user hasn't received any messages in the last (let's say) 20 seconds, I increase the interval to make a request to **fetch_new.php** every 2 seconds instead of every second. If over a minute has passed, I increase it to 3 seconds and so on. This way you won't slow down your application by having a lot of idle users.

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    setTimeout(function()
    { 
        // do something here
    }, 2000); 
});
```

The above code will execute your function every 2 seconds. Don't know about efficiency though. So perhaps another approach would work better.